# How to close pop up window in servlet and redirect the servlet to parent window

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

i am creating a pop up window through jsp and passing some selected values in pop up window to jsp. while doing this i am using servlet ie. from pop up window i am calling servlet and in servlet i am using request dispacher and forwarding the result to jsp. this whole process is working fine, but the new jsp which i am calling from servlet is coming in the same pop up window. how can i close the pop up window in servlet and redirect the servlet to parent window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *how can i close the pop up window in servlet and redirect the servlet to parent window.*

You cannot do this from the servlet side on. You have 2 options:

1. Just do not call the servlet from the popup window, but from the parent window. The popup window should basically only contain some additional data or info and always be closed by JavaScript when it has done its job. The enduser should continue navigating/submitting from the parent window.
2. Let the servlet return a piece of JS code which does roughly the following:

   ```
   window.opener.location = 'newpage.jsp'; // Sets parent window's new URL.
   window.close(); // Close the popup window.
   ```

   This is however an ugly hack.

Comment: oh ok this was very informative i will try with the first step thank u BalusC

Answer (score 0):

Pass to the servlet callback method (javascript) that will close the popup and handle the response in the parent window.